# How to remove certain length of digits from text?

Tags: python, regex

I want to purify my text by removing certain length of digits from it, so I define rule for it. I think `isdigit` is good for dealing with, but if I used this it will discard all digits in the text. in my test, last 10 digits are not contributed to the text, so I could remove it. Here is that I tried:

```
urls = ['variety.com/2017/biz/news/tax-march-donald-trump-protest-1202031487/',
        'variety.com/2018/film/news/list-2018-oscar-nominations-1202668757/']

cols = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4']
make_me = []
for url in urls:
    lst = url.split("/")
    # your business rules go here
    make_me.append([x for x in lst if not x.isdigit() and not x == ""])

df = pd.DataFrame(make_me, columns=cols)
df

res=[]
for i in df.c4: 
    lst=i.split("-") 
    res.append([''.join(x) for x in lst if not x.isdigit()])
```

my attempt discarded all digit in text. I simply want this kind of output:

```
tax march donald trump protest
list 2018 oscar nominations
```

how should I write the rule to get this output? Any idea?

Comment: Can you guarantee that the text to be extracted always comes between last two `/` and before the last `-`?

Comment: @Austin yes, I can guarantee, as you know, last 10 digits are not related to text, so I don't want them in the text. basically I want to construct new locums by splitting curls to get news headline (such as `tax march donald trump protest`) without last 10 digits. Any pretty solution to do this?

Comment: looks like regex is pretty overkill. See my solution down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure python way of doing without additional modules looks like this:

```
urls = ['variety.com/2017/biz/news/tax-march-donald-trump-protest-1202031487/',
        'variety.com/2018/film/news/list-2018-oscar-nominations-1202668757/']

for x in urls:
    print(' '.join(x.rsplit('/', 2)[-2].split('-')[:-1]))

# tax march donald trump protest
# list 2018 oscar nominations
```

If you need a list of output, use a list-comprehension:

```
[' '.join(x.rsplit('/', 2)[-2].split('-')[:-1]) for x in urls]
```

Comment: @woody, do you want a list at the end? If yes, go for it. Don't use otherwise.

Comment: I don't want list, I want to construct new columns from them. since your solution pretty efficient, is that fine to build new dataframe by adding those as new column? how to shape new dataframe? Any idea?

Comment: @woody, sure you can use. The point is list comps are for creating lists. If you need a list to pass while creating dataframe, list comp suits.

Comment: any pretty solution to make that happen?

Comment: @woody, sorry for the delay. Not sure what you are asking. If you are asking how to build dataframe from the inputs you have, please refer to some SO questions (hope there is some) else this is worth a new question. This original question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to extract urls of the same format, use regular expressions

```
import re

urls = ['variety.com/2017/biz/news/tax-march-donald-trump-protest-1202031487/',
        'variety.com/2018/film/news/list-2018-oscar-nominations-1202668757/']
news = []
regex =re.compile(r'/news/(.*)-')
for url in urls:
    extract_id = regex.search(url)
    if extract_id:
        data = extract_id.group(1)
        news.append(data.replace('-',' '))

print(news)
```

**Output**

```
['tax march donald trump protest', 'list 2018 oscar nominations']
```

Edited format to suit the question.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many approaches to this. Use `.rfind('-')` to get rightmost index of '-' and then slice your string. After that you can process the string further.

Comment: As you said the problem is with 'numbers', you can first remove all the unrequired numbers using slicing by finding their index. eg slice from 'news' by its index then also the 10 digits at the end by finding right index of '-' and finally your loop for removing other unwanted characters

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have a very specific rule that would help you - just remove the last 10 characters from the last interesting element.
In this case `lst[-2] = lst[-2][:-12]` right before the `make_me.append` call would do the trick.

If you do want to make it with regex, I'd use the end-of-line marker, $, to make sure the digits were at the end. It would look like
`lst = re.sub('[0-9]{10}/$','',url)`

after importing `re`, of course. This reads as:

re.sub is a substitution method in the regular expressions module, and it changes the matches to the regex in the first parameter with the content in the second parameter; the third parameter is the string where you want to make the substitution.

The regex I wrote matches "a sequence of 10 characters which match any of 0123456789, followed by a / and the end of the string".